# Deriving marginal effects for a bivariate model: ordered probit + linear regression

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, marginal-effect, ordered-probit, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I am having trouble obtaining marginal effects of the following model in Stata, so that I would love to have some help in how to obtain an expression by hand:

I have a system with two equations: an ordered probit and a linear equation. There is only one independent variable in each

1 - linear model: $$y = \alpha + \beta z + \epsilon_1$$.
2 - ordered probit: $$z^* = \gamma x + \epsilon_2 \\ z = j \quad \alpha_{j-1} \leq z^* \leq \alpha_j \quad j \in \{-4, -3, \ \dots \ 3,  \ 4\} $$

To simplify, assume that $\epsilon_2 \sim  N(0, \sigma^2)$ and that $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are potentially correlated.

Now, what is the expression for the marginal effect of $x$ on $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0 $$
because y is not a function of X on your structural equation.
If you go through the reduced form (and I ll take some liberties of notation here, assuming you are using Control function approach:)
$$ y = \alpha + \beta *z + \theta \lambda + u_1 $$
where $ \lambda $  is the generalized residual from your order probit (something similar to the Inverse mills ratio). Your marginal effects is also zero:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0 $$

Because you need to assume $ \lambda $ is assumed constant. Wooldridge (2010) does a similar analogy for the IVprobit model (see section 15.7.2 pg 588).

If you are trying to implement this in Stata by hand, (creating your predict program or using expression or similar), Stata may be trying to estimate marginal effects as follows:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0 +\theta \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x} $$

But this will be incorrect. In fact, again for IV probit, that is what -margins- would do for Stata 14, Stata15, and Stata 16 until an update that happened last year.

Hope this helps.

Wooldridge, J (2010) Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data. 2nd edition.

Comment: thank you, but is there a way to obtain a model in which such effects are possible? I am not actually using an IV, as said by your answer

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Again, it all depends on how you are trying to estimate the model. If you use, for example, mle, and request margins using the option -nochain-, you can obtain the "indirect" effect of X on y, via $\lambda$ If you are more specific with your question, i may be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: for no particular reason (I was just following another paper doing something similar), I was using command cmp in Stata, as in ```cmp (y = z) (z = x), ind($cmp_cont $cmp_oprobit)```